# Protocol to recover from stalled Zeppelin kernels?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I hope this is the appropriate forum.

I have used [jupyter notebooks](http://jupyter.org/) for several years, but just started using [Apache Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/) fairly recently.

It has several potentially advantageous differences. One of them seems to me to be the ease with which the server daemon is launched (or stopped), making Zeppelin easier to install as a shared, collaborative platform.

## Possible to kill only part of *Zeppelin*?

But what can I do, other than `zeppelin-daemon.sh stop`, when a particular language's kernel has frozen or gotten stuck in ridiculously long code?  Sometimes you can pause the paragraph (although the pause seems to also get "stuck" when the kernel is frozen).  But what I really want is a command line way to say something like, "restart the *SparkSQL* kernel" or "kill the current task that the *Python* kernel is working on", while leaving the rest intact.

I want to allow users the flexibility to try things that might "get stuck", and the confidence that a coworker will not bring down their platform via stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restart individual interpreter in the notebook.

[image]

Or restart from interpreter menu

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Moon!  Not sure how I didn't notice that within the interpreter, but it's also strange it wasn't in the documentation anywhere.

This is great and will work well enough for most of my situations, but the Holy Grail would still be if I could simply kill the **current task** rather than restart the interpreter.  That will prevent all objects from being lost.